# Wrong output. Where is my random numbers?

Tags: c#, listview, for-loop, random

I'm new to programming, and I'm reading a book on C#. This code is not outputting what I was expecting.

Here is the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static string stars = "****************************************************************";
    const int MAXVAL = 52;
    const int MAXELEMENTS = 100;

    int[] data = new int[MAXELEMENTS];

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i;
        Random rd = new Random(5);
        int j;
        string buff;

        for (i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            data[i] = rd.Next(MAXVAL);
            buff = " ";
            for (j = 0; j < data[i]; j++)
            {
                buff += "*";
                lstResult.Items.Add(data[i].ToString() + " " + buff);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output:
[image]

**Why isn't there random numbers in an random order in the listview?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output is logical if you do your `Random.Next` call outside the `j` loop and the `Items.Add` inside it.

I suggest moving the `Items.Add` call *behind* the `j` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Take out the 5 after the `Random()`, that is a seed value. Just use the default constructor:

**Seed** - A integer used to set the starting point for generating a series of random numbers.  The seed sets the generator to a random starting point.  A unique seed returns a unique random number sequence.

Because you are using 5 as a seed every time, you are getting repeating numbers

```
   Random rd = new Random();
```

Comment: I thought the number/s where generated in the "data[i] = rd.Next(MAXVAL);"

Comment: shouldn't declaring Random in the constructor and keeping it as a field be better?
if the button gets pressed a lot of times and quickly this might not be the best way to do it? or am i mistaking?

Answer (score 1):

You are seeding the random instance always with the same number `5`. That'll cause repeating numbers. You just have to use the default constructor:

```
Random rd = new Random();
```

Have a look at the example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww.aspx) which shows exactly this behaviour.

By the way, this is also a common pitfall, you should always reuse the same random instance instead of creating always a new one(in a loop) since the seed is created from the current time. If you create randoms very fast you'll get the same seed which causes repeating numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same seed (5) each time with this line `Random rd = new Random(5);`

Use the default constructor to generate a random number:

```
Random rd = new Random();
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your random class without seed.

```
 Random rd = new Random();
```